# How else can I convey the following: sorry for repeating myself?

Tags: phrase-request

I wonder what else (that sounds more natural to a native ear) I can say about being sorry for repeating myself. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

Your statement ("I'm sorry for repeating myself") sounds perfectly natural to my ear. Some other options:

> - I'm sorry if this is repetitive, but...
> - My apologies for being redundant, but...
> - I'm not sure if this has already been said, but...
> - I know we've talked about this at length, but...
> - I'm sorry to repeat myself, but...

Answer (score 5):

Abby's answer has five good options. If you want to add some idiomatic expressions to your list, you could add:

> - Sorry to keep beating a dead horse, but...
> - Sorry if I sound like a broken record, but...

The expression *beating a dead horse* would be appropriate if you think the other person might be getting a little impatient with the fact that you've been saying something over and over again. One [website](http://www.knowyourphrase.com/phrase-meanings/Beating-a-Dead-Horse.html) says:

> *Beating a dead horse*
> **Meaning**
> To bring up an issue that has already been concluded; something that's considered to be pointless.
>
> If an argument erupts and it's one that has been previously settled, then the idiom
> "beating a dead horse" might be said by someone who sees any further discussion on the topic to be meaningless.

On the other hand, one can apologize for *sounding like a broken record* without any impending exasperation required. From [UE](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/broken+record.html):

> When someone sounds like a broken record, they keep on repeating the same things.

I might use the *broken record* expression to describe a small child who is saying the same thing over and over and over again. I might use the *dead horse* expression to describe someone at work who feels adamant about something – who, despite not being able to persuade anyone that his argument is valid, keeps bringing up the matter over and over again. The expressions are a bit more specialized in meaning, but they could still both be used while someone is apologizing for repeating themselves, depending on the situation.